# How can I open a cmd window and pass in hardcoded values using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dos

I have found many solutions that are close to what I want but not exactly it and have had no luck myself.

I am trying to create a script that I can use to automate firewall authentication. I am doing this manually at the minute by opening a cmd window and attempting to telnet to a device/pc behind the firewall. After a short pause I am prompted for username and password.

Is there any way to write a batch file that will open a cmd window and provide these two values?

Currently it goes like this:

```
C:> telnet device (I type this in to prompt authentication)
(short pause)
-- Firewall Authentication --
Username: (asks for input which I provide then press enter)
Password: (same as username)
-- Authentication Successful --
```

Thanks for any help with this. If you need more specifics please comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a small vbscript for its sendkeys.  Lets say if the prompt comes up and it focuses on the username first, then if you can do one TAB and its on password, and you're allowed to use the RETURN key to submit your credentials, you can add this to your batch script:

```
CSCRIPT //NoLogo //B "C:\Folder\sendkeys.vbs"
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 11000 >NUL
```

Then create a file (in this example) called sendkeys.vbs with say Notepad, and add the following lines of code:

```
set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WSCript.shell")

wscript.sleep 5000
wshShell.sendkeys "type username here"
wscript.sleep 1000
wshShell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
wscript.sleep 3000 
wshShell.sendkeys "type password here"
wscript.sleep 1000
wshShell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Quit
```

I do this for auto-sending emails in Thunderbird via the command line.

Comment: Reason for the ping is to create a pause for the vbscript to finish.  If you need a longer pause between when you call telnet and when the sendkeys script will run, you can change the 5000 to something higher (1000 = 1 second)

Comment: Thanks Mechaflash, I knew there must be some way to do this using scripting. As it is a cmd line prompt I cannot TAB to the password but am prompted for it once I have pressed ENTER to submit the username. I will try this approach and let you know - thanks again.

Comment: I'll Edit for Username ENTER Password ENTER.  Changed the middle sleep to 3 seconds in case there's a delay between username prompt and password prompt.

Comment: Sorry for noob question here but the first two lines above that are meant to be for batch script - will they open a cmd window and ping the device behind the firewall? Do I replace the 1.1.1.1 IP with the IP of the device I want to connect to?

Comment: negative.  the PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 8000 >NUL is just a 'ghetto' way of making a batch script 'wait' for a specified amount of time (8000 being 8 seconds).  There are 2 different batch script add-ons you can download that will unlock the ability to use commands like 'Wait' and 'Sleep', but that PING command does just fine.

Comment: and the CSCRIPT line is just a way of calling a vbscript from inside a batch script.  When doing this, it will call your vbscript BUT still run directly to the next command of your batch script.  So, ensure that all your wscript.sleep SUMed up are not larger than the value of your PING -w time. I would make the -w time 1000+ than your wscript.sleep.

Comment: Hi Mechaflash, thanks for your help so far, however I am unsure of how to automate the opening of the cmd window and using the input 'telnet XXXXX' where XXX is the server name. This is what causes the prompt for the keys which the vbscript provides. Do I put this call inside the batch file or the script? And what is the correct syntax to use? Thanks

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear... but from my answer above, the first gray box is the code you will put in your .BAT script. You want to insert that code AFTER the line where you call TELNET. The 2nd gray box is the code you will put in a separate file named sendkeys.vbs.  However, make sure to change the "C:\Folder\sendkeys.vbs" to the correct path where you have placed the sendkeys.vbs file.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, yes I understand the two gray boxes as you described. My problem is the line where I call TELNET, I know the syntax to open a command line window (start cmd) but I cannot find a way to then pass in the command 'TELNET <servername>'. This is my problem, the line before I use the code you have provided above. Hope thats slightly clearer, thanks.

Comment: instead of calling cmd, use the command START telnet <servername>

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid, you can't do this, because telnet is an executable file, so processing of input (user name and password) is just an internal logic of this program.

This would be possible only if telnet supports user name and password as command line arguments.

---

But there is some tricky workaround exists. Ask your friend, a programmer, to write a simple program that

1. Accepts user name and password as command line arguments
2. Runs telnet.exe with redirected console input/output
3. Tracks changes in console output (waits for user input)
4. Simulates typing user name and password
5. Returns the same error code that telnet do